# How to determine Week Numbers in Quarter, when the Quarter starts mid-week?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need some help with part of my query. I am trying to accurately calculate 2 columns. In the first column, I am trying to calculate the Week Number of the fiscal Quarter based on a call date. In the second column, I am wanting to aggregate the Start and End Date of that particular week.

The following query I have used and it has worked perfectly for the past 2 quarters, but now it is no longer functioning correctly, I assume because the current quarter started mid-week on a Tuesday (1/1/2019).

```
, 1 + TRUNC((CALL_DATE - TRUNC(CALL_DATE, 'Q'))/7) as "Week in Quarter"
, TO_CHAR(TRUNC(CALL_DATE, 'IW'), 'MM/DD/YY') ||' - '|| TO_CHAR(TRUNC(CALL_DATE, 'IW') + 4, 'MM/DD/YY') as  "Week Dates"
```

For calls completed on Monday (1/7/2019), it's reflecting that as 'Week 1' in the "Week in Quarter" column, when in actuality that should be considered 'Week 2'.

Also, the "Week Dates" column is labeling the first week of the quarter as '12/31/18 - 01/04/19', when instead I want it to be '01/01/19 - 01/04/19'.

How do I change this code to work for all fiscal quarters regardless of what weekday the quarter starts on? It's almost like I need a case that calculates the first week of the quarter differently?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `( TRUNC( call_date, 'IW' ) - TRUNC( TRUNC( call_date, 'Q' ), 'IW' ) ) / 7 + 1` to find the number of the week in the quarter.

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( call_date ) AS
SELECT DATE '2018-12-20' + LEVEL - 1
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 20;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT call_date,
       ( TRUNC( call_date, 'IW' ) - TRUNC( TRUNC( call_date, 'Q' ), 'IW' ) ) / 7 + 1 
         AS week_of_quarter,
       GREATEST(
         TRUNC( call_date, 'IW' ),
         TRUNC( call_date, 'Q' )
       ) AS start_of_quarter_week,
       LEAST(
         TRUNC( call_date, 'IW' ) + INTERVAL '6' DAY,
         ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( call_date, 'Q' ), 3 ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY
       ) AS end_of_quarter_week
FROM   table_name;
```

**Output**:

```
CALL_DATE | WEEK_OF_QUARTER | START_OF_QUARTER_WEEK | END_OF_QUARTER_WEEK
:-------- | --------------: | :-------------------- | :------------------
20-DEC-18 |              12 | 17-DEC-18             | 23-DEC-18          
21-DEC-18 |              12 | 17-DEC-18             | 23-DEC-18          
22-DEC-18 |              12 | 17-DEC-18             | 23-DEC-18          
23-DEC-18 |              12 | 17-DEC-18             | 23-DEC-18          
24-DEC-18 |              13 | 24-DEC-18             | 30-DEC-18          
25-DEC-18 |              13 | 24-DEC-18             | 30-DEC-18          
26-DEC-18 |              13 | 24-DEC-18             | 30-DEC-18          
27-DEC-18 |              13 | 24-DEC-18             | 30-DEC-18          
28-DEC-18 |              13 | 24-DEC-18             | 30-DEC-18          
29-DEC-18 |              13 | 24-DEC-18             | 30-DEC-18          
30-DEC-18 |              13 | 24-DEC-18             | 30-DEC-18          
31-DEC-18 |              14 | 31-DEC-18             | 31-DEC-18          
01-JAN-19 |               1 | 01-JAN-19             | 06-JAN-19          
02-JAN-19 |               1 | 01-JAN-19             | 06-JAN-19          
03-JAN-19 |               1 | 01-JAN-19             | 06-JAN-19          
04-JAN-19 |               1 | 01-JAN-19             | 06-JAN-19          
05-JAN-19 |               1 | 01-JAN-19             | 06-JAN-19          
06-JAN-19 |               1 | 01-JAN-19             | 06-JAN-19          
07-JAN-19 |               2 | 07-JAN-19             | 13-JAN-19          
08-JAN-19 |               2 | 07-JAN-19             | 13-JAN-19
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=16517e548017993eb547d0be4ce4966a)*

Comment: This isn't quite working either. If I go back to the quarter of July now it's considering the first week of July as Week 2? Also, the date in the End of Quarter Week should reflect Friday's date, if we're considering Monday to be the Start of the Quarter Week (as in the weekdays).

Comment: @Melanie [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=134cc00ccc4745f4d5cede96eeb8b6f2) 2018-07-01 was a Sunday so there was only one day of that week in the 3rd quarter and then 2018-07-02 is a Monday and starts the next week; assuming you want weeks to have their traditional (ISO) meaning of running for 7 days from Monday to Sunday. If you do not intend that to be the meaning of a week then you need to specify what you mean by "a week".

Comment: By "week" I mean Work Week. So the week in which the first Work Day occurs, is what I want to consider as Week 1. That's what's making this so complicated. I found a formula that works to calculate this in excel, but cannot translate it into PL-SQL. Here is my formula in Excel if that helps anyone translate this to SQL (A2 being the Call_Date I'm referencing): `=1+(WEEKNUM(A2))-(WEEKNUM(DATE(YEAR(A2),LOOKUP(MONTH(A2),{1,4,7,10}),1)))`

Comment: @Melanie that should be an edit to your question (or a new question).

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server/T-SQL, you can use this code to get the week of the quarter.

```
1+(DATEPART(WW,[call_date])-DATEPART(WW,DATEADD(QQ,DATEDIFF(QQ,0,[call_date]),0)))
```